# How to export the user's data and restrict table rownum?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, export

I want export data something like this.

```
exp xxx/xxx file=d:\xxx.dmp owner=xxx query=\"where rownum < 1000\"
```

But I get an error `"QUERY parameter is only use in table mode"`

Oracle version 10g

Comment: You can only specify a query when exporting a single table (as opposed to a whole schema as you are doing).

Answer (score 2):

As @Thilo says, with `exp` you can only user the `query` parameter in table mode. If you're able to use the newer data pump functionality, via the `expdp` command, you can apply a similar [`query` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#sthref156) to the whole export.

Answer (score 1):

@Thilo is right, you can [export a single table or a SUBSET of a single table](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ#Can_one_export_a_subset_of_a_table.3F)

I also recommend reading [Tom's advice](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:478275606639) in regards to using parfile

Comment: That's doing exactly what @Thilo said, applying `query` when exporting a single table.

Comment: @AlexPoole you're right - I fixed the answer. It would have been clearer if he wrote that the "tables" parameter is missing.